# Close all windows on Reload on an Electron Application

Tags: electron

I have an electron desktop application which opens 2 new windows when I load it, the code to open the new windows is this:

```
electron = require('electron')
win = electron.remote.getCurrentWindow();
BrowserWindow = electron.remote.BrowserWindow;

wind = new BrowserWindow({  
                            width: 400, 
                            height: 200, 
                            x:3,
                            y:12,
                            frame: false, 
                            // transparent: true,
                            alwaysOnTop: true,    // Add this line
                            // skipTaskbar:true, // don't show icon on taskbar
                            opacity:0.9,

                        })
```

Now when I'm testing my application, I use the Reload command a lot (ctrl+R on windows). My problem is that when I do it, the windows remain open and it opens more windows on top of it.

How can I make Reload close all windows?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `onbeforeunload` event is triggered (In the renderer)  when a window is closed or reloaded. You can use this to close the individual window.

Otherwise you can inform electron via a IPC message to close all your windows for you.

Something like this should do the job.

```
// renderer/index.js
const {ipcRenderer} = require('electron')
ipcRenderer.send('my-closeallwindowsasap-channel') // can have arguments

// -------------------------------------------------------

// main/index.js
ipcMain.on('my-closeallwindowsasap-channel', (event, arg) => {
  BrowserWindow.getAllWindows().forEach(window => {
    window.close()
  })
})
```